# Can I place a caching server in a remote location?

Tags: server, cache

Let's say I have one server acting as [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) server located in the UK, and I want to add a caching server, for example, [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29) or [Memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached).

1. Can I add a caching server which is located in the US?
2. Will there be any delay in fetching the cached content from the remote location?

Comment: 1) Yes, why not? 2) Well, the closer to the UK the better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could do this, but it's not a good idea. Ignoring the security aspect, there will be a delay of at least 100-150ms when fetching cached content (the latency between your UK and US servers). This is an eternity in page generation terms.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, this can be done. Although you will have to make sure that the daemon is setup to accept external connections. Be sure to take a look at [this question on authentication /w an external Memcached server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16177084/491494).
2. Delay can depend on a number of factors - Although, as William David Edwards pointed out, closer is better.